# MPI_Waitall error for asynchronous MPI_Irecv

Tags: c, asynchronous, mpi, wait, openmpi

I have used 2 MPI_Irecv followed by 2 MPI_Send and then MPI_Waitall for both the MPI_Irecv as follows. I have written this same block of code again after a few calculations. But it seems that the MPI processes are failing in the first block of code itself.

My communication is such that a matrix is split horizontally as the no of MPI processes and the communication occurs only between the boundaries of the matrix with below matrix grid sending 'start' / first row to above matrix grid and above matrix grid sending 'end'/last row to below matrix grid.

```
MPI_Request request[2];
MPI_Status status[2];
double grid[size];
double grida[size];
.
.
.
<Calculation for grid2[][]>
...

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (world_rank != 0){
    MPI_Irecv(&grid, size, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);
    printf("1 MPI_Irecv");
    }
    if (world_rank != world_size-1){
    MPI_Irecv(&grida, size, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
    printf("2 MPI_Irecv");
    }
    if (world_rank != world_size-1){
    MPI_Send(grid2[end], size, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("1 MPI_Send");
    }
    if (world_rank != 0){
    MPI_Send(grid2[start], size, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("2 MPI_Send");
    }
    MPI_Waitall(2, request, status); 

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

.
.
.

<Again the above code but without the initialization of MPI_Request and MPI_Status>
```

But for this I'm getting the error:

```
 *** Process received signal ***
 Signal: Bus error: 10 (10)
 Signal code: Non-existant physical address (2)
 Failing at address: 0x108bc91e3
 [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff50b65f5a _sigtramp + 26
 [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x000000010c61523d 0x0 + 4502671933
 [ 2] 0   libmpi.20.dylib                     0x0000000108bc8e4a MPI_Waitall + 154
 [ 3] 0   dist-jacobi                         0x0000000104b55770 Work + 1488
 [ 4] 0   dist-jacobi                         0x0000000104b54f01 main + 561
 [ 5] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff508e5145 start + 1
 [ 6] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
 *** End of error message ***
 *** An error occurred in MPI_Waitall
 *** reported by process [1969881089,3]
 *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
 *** MPI_ERR_REQUEST: invalid request
 *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
 ***    and potentially your MPI job)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node dhcp-10 exited on signal 10 (Bus error: 10).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why is Waitall throwing error, and how is `printf("1 MPI_Irecv");` not being printed. Everything before this print statement is getting printed properly.

The code works with MPI_Wait() and MPI_Isend() as follows:

```
 // insert barrier 
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (world_rank != 0){
    MPI_Irecv(&grid, size*2, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
    printf("1 MPI_Irecv");
    }
    if (world_rank != world_size-1){
    MPI_Irecv(&grida, size*2, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);
    printf("2 MPI_Irecv");
    }
    if (world_rank != world_size-1){
    MPI_Isend(grid2[end], size*2, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
    printf("1 MPI_Send");
    }
    if (world_rank != 0){
    MPI_Isend(grid2[start], size*2, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,  &request[1]);
    printf("2 MPI_Send");
    }
    //MPI_Waitall(2, request, status); 
    MPI_Wait(&request[0], &status[0]);
    MPI_Wait(&request[1], &status[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`request[0]` is used uninitialized on the last rank, and `request[1]` is used uninitialized on the first rank.

A possible fix is to statically initialize the `request` array (assuming it is not used anywhere else in your code).

```
MPI_Request request[2] = {MPI_REQUEST_NULL, MPI_REQUEST_NULL};
```

As a side note, you might want to consider renaming `request` into `requests` and `status` into `statuses` to make it crystal clear these are arrays and not scalars.